# How do i get my "player1" to reset to its original coordinates when i press yes on retrying the game

Tags: java

I am having trouble with getting "player1" reseting to its original coordinates when prompted to wanting to retry again. This window shows up on collision with other cubes moving in x-axis!  I have provided a direct download [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/nq44ke09fxydzc9/DodgeTest.java?dl=0) for my java.class.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Next time if possible try translating the comments and text in your program to English, some of it I cannot read because in a different language and doesn't show up on my computer :/. I don't mean to force  you to use English but would be easier for every individual to understand, since it is the most used language in the world.

Comment: @RileyCarney Well, really its the third most used language in the world after Mandarin and Spanish - however SO is still an English based website with English speaking devs so it definitely helps.

Answer (score 0):

**Reset all the coordinates for each object, including the player, back to their original coordinates and update it.** The reason it is having trouble with collision with what I could read from your application (some of it is in a different language so sorry) is because it is saying that **the player is colliding with another objects x and y.** To prevent this, if you set all the objects to their original positions, if your game could run in the beginning with the objects x and y coordinates like this, it would be able to run after with the objects reset to their previous positions.

You can do this by redefining all the objects, such as:

```
        player1 = new SquareMod(400, 730, 20); // Karaktären man styr

        hinder1 = new SquareMod(600, 400, 20); // Kub 1

        hinder2 = new SquareMod(555, 430, 20); // Kub 2

        //....

        hinder21 = new SquareMod(69, 100, 20); // Kub 21

        Finishline1 = new SquareMod(0,0, 100);

        Finishline2 = new SquareMod(100, 0, 100);

        //....

        Finishline9 = new SquareMod(800, 0, 100);
```

Also I highly suggest adding arrays, it will cut down a huge amount of lines in your code because you can just check for each instance of the array, instead of each variable you defined in the code.

Comment: I can translate the whole class for you if needed. I didnt quite understand. What do i type to reset the coordinates?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how the objects are generated, but from what I can gleam you can do this: At the beginning of your program, use `.getX()` and `.getY()` on the objects to get their original coordinates. I'm assuming there are methods such as `.setX()` and `.setY()` as well that would allow you to set the X and Y's for the objects as well, so if needed you could read their initial coordinates, then when you need the game to reset set them back what you read.

Comment: Also, why don't you use a class array? It would be much easier in my opinion to use `SquareMod[] hinder = new SquareMod[21];` and `SquareMod[] Mållinje = new SquareMod[9];` then setting each of the indexes to a `new SquareMod(x, y, z)` instead of listing out a bunch of them. You could also check the collision much easier by making a loop which checks each collision in the object array, instead of checking each object separately in your code.

Comment: I also just realized the `new SquareMod(x, y, z)` `x` and `y` are probably location, while `z` is health or something? You would just need to set their values to the `x` and `y` you defined at the start.

Comment: Another idea if there isn't any `.setX` or `.setY` method is just to redefine all the objects again, an example being: `hinder1 = new SquareMod(600, 400, 20)`

Comment: Unfortunately .setX() does not exist.. atleast it didnt work for me. Ive translated the whole class into english for you to better understand, (except for the comments wich are for my teacher) https://www.dropbox.com/s/nq44ke09fxydzc9/DodgeTest.java?dl=0

Comment: Just redefine the object like I said, you don't have to write `SquareMod` infront of it but reset every object you have as `new SquareMod(x, y, z)` and it should work.

Comment: Ive just started with programing in my school so unfortunately Im not familiar with different ways of reaching the same "goal" but much more simpler. Im like on my 4th week or something.. Thanks man ill try it out! I really appreciate the help

Comment: No problem, I edited my post for one thing that will work.